# Looping through Pandas dataframe to generate list - most efficient way

Tags: loops, pandas

I have a dataframe in the following format (actually ~200,000 rows. Of these ~20% are active - 'Y', the rest are 'N'):

```
active  adtype           body      eng          first scan   id
N       Private Seller Car  Â Coupe Â 8cyl 4.7L     31/01/2016  SSE-AD-3469148
Y       Dealer: Near New    Â Coupe Â 12cyl 6.5L    31/01/2016  OAG-AD-12326299
N       Dealer: Used Car    Â Coupe Â 12cyl 6.5L    31/01/2016  OAG-AD-6834787
```

I'm creating a list of the ids that are then cross-checked against some website scrape data to find new items:

```
database_ids = database_records['id'].tolist() #simple list of ad IDs from CSV
database_ids = set(database_ids)
database_dicts = database_records.to_dict(orient='records') #Converted to list of dicts  
newads = []
adscrape_ids = []

#Search database for existing ads. Append new ads to 'newads'
 for ad in adscrape:
     ad['last scan'] = date
     ad['active'] = 'Y'
     adscrape_ids.append(ad['id'])
     if ad['id'] not in database_ids:
         ad['first scan'] = date
         print 'new ad:',ad
         newads.append(ad)
```

I want to speed this process up by limiting database_ids to only ids that are still active ('Y'). Is there any pandas-specific, efficient way of doing this, or should I just create a loop:

```
for row in database_dicts:
    if row['active'] == 'Y':
        database_ids.append(row['id'])
database_ids = set(database_ids)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this far more efficiently (I'm willing to bet you'll be able to see a noticeable difference in speed):

```
set(database_dicts[database_dicts.active == 'Y']['id'].unique())
```

- `database_dicts[database_dicts.active == 'Y']` filters and retains the rows you want.
- `.unique()` will return the unique values (in this case, of the `id` column).

In general, you should try to do as much as possible while the data is in the DataFrame - it is *much* more efficient than loops and pure Python.